# Win32_Service shoots management Exception(access denied)

Tags: asp.net, wmi

```
ManagementObjectSearcher servSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(theScope, new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service"));                    
foreach (ManagementObject servObj in servSearcher.Get()){

}
```

`Win32_Process` does not trigger any error but when trying to access `Win32_Service` it shoots *management Exception(access denied)*

```
System.Management.ManagementException: Access denied at 
System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)at
System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set or add dword

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system\LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy = 1
```

on the machine you want to connect to. In my case it worked even without restart.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following by adding a `ManagementScope` and a `ConnectionOptions` class:

```
 ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
 options.EnablePrivileges = true;
 options.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

 ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\FullComputerName\\root\\cimv2",options);

 ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service");
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query); 

 ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get(); 

 foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection) {
     Console.WriteLine(m["CheckPoint"]); 
 }
```

More on the [ConnectionOptions class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions.aspx)

Comment: i have already done so..i m trying to access remote machine's services.I was successfull in accessing remote machine's process.

Comment: Just replace the `\\\\FullComputerName\\root\\cimv2` with your remote computer

Comment: Have you explicity tried to set the service account username and password in the ConnectionOptions.Username field?

Comment: yes..options.username and options.password fields are set.I have done settings in Dcomcnfg.exe and gpedit.msc is there anything else to done?Like any settings?

Comment: I've added `options.EnablePrivileges = true;` and 
 `options.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;` to my answer. Verify if this might help

Comment: ok..shall chk that..but is there any additional settings to be done apart from that?

Comment: yes i have given options.EnablePrivileges = true; and options.Impersonation =Impersonate also but still it isnt working..

Comment: Worked after i followed the below steps:   

1. Click Start, click Run, type cmd, and then click OK.(Run as Admin)
2. Type the following command at the command prompt, and then press ENTER:
    sc sdset SCMANAGER D:(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)(A;;KA;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;KA;;;WD)(AU;OIIOFA;GA;;;WD)